# directional derivative and continuity

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

$f:\mathbb{R}^{2}\to\mathbb{R}$
  , we're given that for any $ v\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$
  the directional derivative $ \nabla_{v}f\left(0,0\right)$
  exists.

1) Is $f$ continuous at $ \left(0,0\right)?$

2) Additionally, if we assume that $f$ is continuous at $ \mathbb{R}^{2}\setminus\left\{ 0,0\right\}$ ,
  is $f$ continuous at $ \left(0,0\right)?$

Comment: See [here](http://people.whitman.edu/~hundledr/courses/M225/Ch14/Example_DirectionalDeriv.pdf) for an example showing that both questions have negative answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw around each point $(x_n,y_n):=\left({1\over n},{1\over n^2}\right)$ $\ (n\geq 1)$ a small circle of radius ${1\over n^3}$ and erect on this circle a cone of hight $1$ having its tip at $(x_n,y_n,1)$. Let the graph of $f$ consist of the union of these conical surfaces, and add to that the plane minus the small circles. Then $f$ is continuous on ${\mathbb R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, but not at $(0,0)$. Furthermore all directional derivatives $\nabla_v f(0,0)$ exist and are $=0$.